# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'description'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new in Python3. I wrote a little text-adventure but i don't know how to use the input string to access the object properties.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

sword = Object("sword","a broken sword")

def lookat(item):
    print("You see " + item.description)

input = input() # User wrote sword
lookat(input)
```

I always get this error

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'description'**

How do I fix this error? thanks for helping me

**Update**

The input ist the user input, so he wrote "sword"
input = input()

Comment: You assign `input` the value `"sword"` (a string) and then pass it to `lookat()`, which tries to access the `.description` of that value, but since a string has no `.description`, you get that error. You probably meant to write `input = sword` (without the quotes) (by the way, it's a bad idea to name variables the same as builtin functions like `input()`)

Comment: thanks for your answer... sure but the input is the user Input. input = input(), so he wrote "sword" and after i wanna get those attributes from the sword object.

Comment: Referring to a named variable in Python directly based on user input is not impossible in Python, but a very bad idea - look at dictionaries. You probably want to keep your objects in a dictionary, so you can look them up by their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
lookat(sword)
```

As it is your code passes a string to `lookat()`, however, the function expects an `Object`, which `sword` is.

The attribute error occurs because strings do not have an attribute named `description`.

Update

Use a dictionary to map the user input string to an object. Then lookup the corresponding object and pass that to `lookat()`:

```
named_objects = {'sword': Object("sword", "a broken sword")}

name = input('Which object? ')
obj = named_objects.get(name)
if obj:
    lookat(obj)
else:
    print(f'There is no object named {name!r}')
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but the input ist the user input, so he wrote "sword" 
input = input() # User wrote sword
lookat(input)

Comment: Don't name your variables to be the same as builtin functions or classes.